# Can't find checkbox element by name contains, using Selenium Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a checkbox that only has a name.

Here is the HTML:

```
<td class="checkbox-column"><input type="checkbox" name="link-active[138]"></td>
```

Here is my latest attempt to find the element, I have tried a lot of different methods. I also need to grab it without the "[127]" part since that is dynamic in this case.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'link-active')]]")).click();
```

Comment: you can simply use this : `//input[contains(@name,'link-active')]`

Comment: Does anyone know a good way to debug the fact that this element is now found, but wont click with the .click() at the end.

Comment: How many check boxes are there ? with random generated IDs

Comment: The only other checkbox on the page is this one:

       

           <input name="PageForm[load_in_new_tab]" id="PageForm_load_in_new_tab" value="1" type="checkbox">

Comment: When I select the element and hit "Copy xpath" this is what it gives:
      //*[@id="links"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/input

Comment: The radio buttons and the checkbox click might not save if the clicking is done fast. I myself faced similar issue when i had to click multiple radio-buttons and save my selection. This is not the issue with the clicking itself. Try to wait for the for few seconds after you click on the checkbox then proceed to your next step.

Comment: @PJAutomator added a 10 sec implicit wait after and it has the same behavior, clicks the checkbox but doesnt save the functionality after saving. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @NickaBrick What do you do after you click on the checkbox ? Do you hit a save button ?

Comment: Yep I add a letter to a text field that is "Changes" and click a save button. Here is the code for that:

`driver.findElement(By.id("change-history")).sendKeys("s");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Save and Return']"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong xpath, correct xpath is:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'link-active')]")).click();
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't throw an ElementNotFound error, but it also doesn't end up clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Check if this xapth matches with more than one element.

Comment: This is the only checkbox with a name like that on the page

Comment: Open the web page with chrome, then activate the developer tools.  Press ctrl-F to call up the search box, enter the xpath ALL THREE OF US gave you, and see if it shows only one match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the name attribute.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'link-active')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

xpath has a name attribute method, you can try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(name(),'link-active')]")).click();
```

Comment: @name not name()

Comment: @BillHileman, as I have mentioned in my answer above. Xpath has name() method also which internally calls name attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can simply introduce `webdriverwait` to let your script knows that it is visible and enabled and then you can try to click. Like this :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'link-active')]"))).click();
```

Comment: Hmm even with the conditional wait, it doesn't activate the checkbox.

Comment: Is the checkbox visible in UI when your script are being executed ?

Comment: Yep, no errors thrown when using your ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable. Plus I can physically see it when running the test

Comment: Did you try with `thread.sleep(4000)` which is worst case of the explicit wait. Before clicking on it just write it and then click it , let's see if that works then we can easily replace that with webdriverwait.

Comment: So add "thread.sleep(4000)" before "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'link-active')]")).click();" ?

Comment: yes , let's see if that works the we can easily replace it.

Comment: Still comes back unchecked

Comment: Wait, I physically saw it check the box that time.. but it won't save the page with that active...

Comment: Ok , Just print this : `System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'link-active')]")).size());`

Comment: My issue might be after the click. For some reason it isn't saving that checkbox active input

Comment: Just remove every code and print the code which I have given in the upper comment box.

Comment: Got to go to lunch, but I think I can debug why the checkbox is becoming inactive after that click. Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: That output '0'

Comment: Then it is obvious that it is not finding the element.  You will have to use different locator , Can you update the code with little bit of HTML , just outer of this input tag.

Comment: Updated to have more HTML

Comment: Yep, it's unable to find the element at all now

Comment: The class "checkbox-column" is the only addition to the HTML. It is the only thing surrounding it. However, I discovered the issue. It was finding the checkbox element, but my next statement (the one to save the checking action) wasnt working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Anyhow I hope your problems has been solved. Thank you for giving the update though.